# Android. Адаптация приложения к разным дисплеям

Tags: android

Сделал небольшую игру, тестировал на смертфоне с дисплеем 1920 х 1080. Естественно теперь возникает вопрос как это все будет работать на других дисплеях. Вначале создал класс который возвращает число пропорциональности, на которое нужно делить все рисование , если дисплеи будут с меньшим экраном чем 1920 (при соотношении сторон как у HD). Но делить каждую мелочь на число - очень все страшно выглядит с точки зрения  читаемости кода. Поэтому решил просто продублировать классы под каждый дисплей и там вносить нужные параметры, так надежнее и понятнее. Увеличится ли существенно вес программы при таком дубляже классов? Если программа все ровно выберет только один вариант классов под свой дисплей, остальные обьекты создаваться же не будут ? И соответственно не должно уходить на них особо память больше нескольких килобайт ? Адаптация под разные дисплеи так решается или другим путем?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Внушительное количество "дисплеев" под свои нужды можно протестировать в эмуляторе, например [Genimotion](https://www.genymotion.com/). Дублировать классы под каждый дисплей однозначно не решение.